# Card residence eu family

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, international-travel

Le directive 2004/38/CE he say if you have card resident UE membre family you can travel in uk accompany citizen EEA without visa .  My question is " whats document need in the border ??

Answer (score 1):

You need your passport or travel document, your Article 10 residence card, and you must be travelling with or joining your EU national family member.

Comment: According to https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card you will also need evidence that you are the family member of an EEA citizen (for example, your marriage certificate or birth certificate), and if you are not travelling with your EEA citizen family member, you will also need to show evidence that:
 - your EU, EEA or Swiss family member is in the UK, and
 - your family member has a right of residence in the UK